# Перезапись данных в файл

Tags: java, nio2

Как сделать так, чтобы файл пересоздавался заново при каждом запуске программы? Сейчас создаю файл для записи таким образом:

```
 try {
            Files.createFile(file);
            Files.writeString(file, "Hello nio", StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Есть идея проверять на наличие файла, потом удалять, если есть и создавать новый, но кажется, что это не лучший вариант.

Comment: Ну добавьте в начало `Files.writeString(file, "");`. Суть в том, что по умолчанию файл перед записью очищается или создаётся, если его нет.

Comment: Может быть заменить StandardOpenOption.APPEND на другое значение енума? Попробуйте несколько вариантов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку бизнес логика у этого участка кода не сложная, то можно использовать устаревший класс File (Files более новая версия, но здесь она не к чему).

Метод write() в классе File по умолчанию будет перезаписывать файл.